# How to combine multiple query types in MS Access 2010?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a query that is created in VBA and selects column information from two other tables and creates a new table with that information.

Existing Query:

> Select Prem.longitude, Prem.latitude,
>   DataByColl.[MIU ID], DataByColl.[Avg
>   RSSI], Prem.prem_addr1
>   Into [FifthAveMeshInput]
>   From [Prem]
>   Left
>   Join DataByColl
>   ON (Prem.meter_miu_id
>   = DataByColl.[MIU ID] AND DataByColl.Collector = ("Fifth Ave."))
>   ORDER BY DataByColl.[Avg RSSI] desc

I would like to add to this two fields. One called Index that is auto incremented starting at a value of 2 as well as one called MeterType that is a number with all values set to 0. Is it possible to have all of these in one query or would I have to use separate queries to accomplish this? And if I would need to use separate queries which ones would I need and in what order?

Comment: What is `ORDER BY DataByColl.[Avg RSSI] desc` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has to be two steps:

1. Create the table (you can use SQL
   DDL `CREATE TABLE...` syntax for
   this).
2. Populate the table using `INSERT
   INTO..SELECT`.

One issue with the above is that you have to first discover the data types of the columns in your query and use them in the table creation step.

Alternatively:

1. Create the table using
   `SELECT..INTO..FROM`.
2. Alter the table to add the new
   columns.

One issue with the above is that you'd need to populate the auto-increment values yourself (if I am correct in thinking one can't add the auto-increment property to an existing column), which may actually defeat the object of having an auto-increment column in the first place!

Comment: Thanks, I thought that this would be the answer but I thought I'd check just in case.